# Any ideas why <strong> tag doesn't work but CSS does?

Tags: css, html, google-font-api

```
<span class="bold">Some Title</span>
```

```css
.bold
{
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

This renders boldly, however this:

```
<strong>Some Title</strong>
```

Does not.  It just renders as regular text.  I'm using the HTML5 doctype and the Google font:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans&v2' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Anyone experienced this as well?

Edit:  BoltClock suggested it might be CSS reset, here's the chunk for `<strong>`

```css
/** CSS Reset **/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a CSS reset that forgot to "reset" styles for `strong`?

Comment: If you are trying this in jsfiddle uncheck `Normalized CSS`

Comment: @Bolt yes I am!  But I'm not sure how this would interfere?

Comment: I posted an answer to explain.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If there is nothing else for `strong`, then there's your problem (or rather, the CSS reset's problem).

The `font: inherit` style, together with all those selectors, is asking everything to inherit every font style from its parent. The default weight is, obviously, `normal`, so `strong` text is no longer bold until you redeclare it:

```css
strong { font-weight: bold; }
```

(Some other obvious elements to reset styles for are `b`, `em`, `i`, code elements, quote elements, tables, headings, lists, etc.)

Comment: tl;dr `inherit` means inherit from parent element, not inherit browser defaults

Answer (score 10):

add:

```css
strong{
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

to your CSS. Maybe somewhere you reset this tag.

Answer (score 1):

Those resets are reseting not just padding and margins, as BoltClock explained, `font:inherit` can break your browsers deafault behaviour with displaying proper fonts style.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to BoltClock's answer, I also found out that we must use the complete tag names for closing the tags, otherwise the STRONG tag used afterwards doesn't work.
For example,

> `<H1> heading </H1>`

```
instead of,
```

> `<H1> heading </>`

Comment: Is the situation where `</>` is actually valid? Genuinely curious

Comment: looks like they are not valid.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5

Comment: I think that question is discussing self closing such as `<img />` - I was curious about the use of `</>`

Comment: </> or <img/> is not valid, according to the specs, but the browser still renders it. it should be like this: <img> </img>.
 it is under the section "end tags" have a look: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was Angular Material `.mat-option` class, for some reason using `<b>` or `<strong>` didn't work with their font. Changing their font to another one solved the issue for me.